# How to select slider speed settings for two different gallery sliders

Tags: javascript, wordpress, slider, bxslider

Hello I am looking to adjust the speed on individual Sliders on my homepage. These are Specific to the theme itself. Is there a way to adjust the JS to allow this?

https://americanmotorcyclist.com/

2 Slider galleries are: Live member news and Industry Press release

```
// BxSlider JS Settings.
if ( typeof jQuery.fn.bxSlider !== 'undefined' ) {
    jQuery( '.widget_slider_area_rotate' ).bxSlider( {
        mode           : 'horizontal',
        speed          : 1500,
        auto           : true,
        pause          : 5000,
        adaptiveHeight : true,
        nextText       : '',
        prevText       : '',
        nextSelector   : '.slide-next',
        prevSelector   : '.slide-prev',
        pager          : false,
        tickerHover    : true
    } );

    jQuery( '.blog .gallery-images, .archive .gallery-images, .search .gallery-images, .single-post .gallery-images' ).bxSlider( {
        mode           : 'fade',
        speed          : 1500,
        auto           : true,
        pause          : 3000,
        adaptiveHeight : true,
        nextText       : '',
        prevText       : '',
        nextSelector   : '.slide-next',
        prevSelector   : '.slide-prev',
        pager          : false
    } );
}
```

} );

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to cycle faster then change the pause value as this most likely represents the amount of time they stay on a certain slide before moving on. This time is represented in MS so 3000 = 3s.